# Slow / Low fps at pipboy inventory, crafting menus, NPC talk, shopping menu etc, how to fix?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

For no apparent reason, my inventory or dialog options etc; all the 2D menus (FalloutNV is 3D but menus are 2D), become utterly slow, while outside of these menus the game (3D) runs smoothly good; Also, when dialog with NPC is beggining, the 2D menu is slow and the 3D of the NPC becomes slow too!

**Workarounds that wont completely stop the problem**
A) - Sometimes if I open the console and type `pcb` the inventory becomes fast and usable again;
B) - another thing that helps is to: 1) open console; 2) click on a container; 3) type at console `player.removeallitems 012345` (where 012345 is the container id that you just clicked); This also helps to fix FPS problems on 3D normal gameplay.

But other times these wont work, forcing me to restart the game (close/run again), what takes about 2min :(

I have mods installed to change the pipboy menu, but there is nothing installed to change shopping and crafting menus, so I cant link it as the source of the problem...

Any idea what I could look for? My guess is it could be related to graphics configurations, but I already turned off Antialiasing (to fix VATS that for no reason used to become unusable). I researched a lot and made several tests to no avail :(

Answer (score 1):

Bunch of people are complaining about pipboy and menu lags,years after the release in particular after OWB expansion.Not to mention that they are already slow and laggy even when they are functioning properly.

Unfortunately no solid fixes are found,they are mostly subjective and weird fixes...Like ones you are trying out.

Some **quest or mod items** are known to ruin your menu,especially if you have lots of mods installed or large quantities of same item in inventory.Try eliminating mods and **clustered items** one by one.

The usual **driver updates** and installing **3rd party programs**(.NET,MVisual c++,PhysX,DirectX) provided with game installation(newer or different versions than ones provided by game can cause issues).

Also look for the **multisampling** in you driver options or game options...This thing causes a bunch of weird problems all around,even when it works you will need really god rig to support it.

**[The Nvidia d3d9 perf fix Mod](http://newvegas.nexusmods.com/mods/34778/?)** thing used to solve a bunch of graphical problems early on.

And lasty there is the desperate move of randomly tweaking things in **configuration .ini file**

Comment: I tried the multisampling directly changing on ini files but the problem still happened; now I am insisting on `player.removeallitems 012345` option and after 3 times I am still being able to avoid restarting (close/open) the game, I will make it sure before editing the initial post about option (C); so I believe your tip about items may be the right one (that made me insist on option (C))! I will do more tests, may be I can find the culprit mod and update it..

Comment: I found several culprits.. but many I like; it will be hard to uninstall these mods.. if it could be fixed..; anyway I think this is the right answer; thx!

Comment: good news man, check the answer I posted!

Answer (score 1):

Just install these two mods:

[Zan AutoPurge Crash Protector - New Vegas Edition](http://www.nexusmods.com/newvegas/mods/49319)

[NVAC - New Vegas Anti Crash](http://www.nexusmods.com/newvegas/mods/53635)

After this, almost all problems are gone!
The game runs incredibly smooth for the first time ever!
I still have rare random crashes but that may be an engine flaw that cannot be fixed by users..